# div displaying a margin

Tags: html, margin, css

i am trying to make a game board using `div`s with different `background-color`s so i wrote some simple css (i am just figuring out how to do it at this stage, and i wrote the `div`s in manually - so im not including the html/js)

```
.grass {
    background-color: oliveDrab;
}

.dirt {
    background-color: sandyBrown;
}

div{
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

when i rendered it, and there was a margin. like so:

[image: margin added]

so i checked firebug and it shows `margin`,`border`, and `padding` is `0`**!!**

[image: no margin in style]

[DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/ydaWg/).

i am being led to feel i am missing some extremely basic css knowledge here.

Comment: The ID attribute is supposed to be unique. It looks like you have a ton of HTML Elements with an id of "board".

Comment: You might also want to look into `box-sizing: border-box;`

http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: @CoryDanielson i noted this is just a test, i wrote this by copy-pasting, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @j08691: Inline and inline-block level elements are sensitive to white space.

But no need to adjust your html markup with:

```
div {
   height: 25px;
   width: 25px;
   display: block;
   float: left;
}

br { 
   clear: both; 
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/ydaWg/20/).

Comment: @tryingToGetProgramming: Bonus, drop the br's in your html and use nth-child. Eg: div:nth-child(6n+7) { clear:left; }

Answer (score 6):

Inline and inline-block level elements are sensitive to white space.

Here's a jsFiddle example of your demo with the white space in the first line removed.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ydaWg/1/)**

```
<div id = "board" class = "grass"></div><div id = "board" class = "grass"></div><div id = "board" class = "grass"></div><div id = "board" class = "grass"></div><div id = "board" class = "grass"></div><div id = "board" class = "grass"></div>
```

Comment: omfg i didnt realize there was a space.

Comment: Aside from removing the white space you can see this site for a few other techniques to use http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block

Comment: this would produce really ugly and difficult to work with HTML. Also, the ID's need to be fixed.

Comment: @CoryDanielson - I explained to the OP the reason for the problem and posted several solutions. Not much more that can be done.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight - I don't mind downvotes provided there's some construction criticism.

Answer (score 4):

It is because there are `inline-block` elements.

Either remove the white space in your markup, add a negative margin, or using float elements as opposed to `display:inline-block`.

[**Here is another example:**](http://jsfiddle.net/ydaWg/19/)

Probably the best solution.

```
body {
    width:150px;
}
div {
    float:left;
}
```

[**jsFiddle with negative margins**](http://jsfiddle.net/ydaWg/7/)

[**jsFiddle with white space removed**](http://jsfiddle.net/ydaWg/16/)

Comment: @allcaps thats the best answer i saw so far, if u make that a answer i will accept.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight I include floats in my update.. http://jsfiddle.net/ydaWg/19/

Comment: @JoshC actually i already accepted one, anyway thnx and `+40` rep well-earned.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight wow dude. I was the first to answer to!

Comment: @JoshC i know, but his is short and sweet, and is what i was rlly looking 4... i wish i could add some more rep 2 u 4 ur help.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight The only way I could have gotten rep was the accepted answer :p I maxed out on my rep for the day. 200 limit. Its all good xD

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't need text set `font-size` style to `0`. This way white-spaces will not interfere.

```
body {
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ydaWg/17/)

Comment: That's also a good little hack, however, if you did *need* to use font, `ems` wouldn't work.

Comment: @JoshC it works if i am inside a "container" `div` which it will be.